# How to make VS Code update the Python autocomplete and installed modules caches?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VS Code will recognize available python packages and modules.

In this case, I started a VS Code session without a python package installed.

[image]

I then opened a terminal (in VS Code) and ran a `pip install` command to install the missing packages (the python interpreter for this project is set to a virtualenv that lives inside my project directory).  However, VS Code still shows these packages as unresolved.

If I close and reopen VS Code, it picks up the new packages. Is there a better way of getting VS Code to automatically pick up these changes than restarting?

Comment: Did you try saving the file?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, saving doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 7):

Probably similar to restarting but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > Reload Window should do it, without clearing your opened files

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work as well. Though it would be nice if there was a better way than reloading all my editors and plugins.